# check for time overlap (ruby/mysql)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 columns: start_time and end_time that look like this: "00:00:05", "00:00:10" (mysql time).

My question follows. How can I validate that one record doesn't overlap any other record already in the table so that it is unique, for example:

"00:00:10", "00:00:20" overlaps "00:00:05", "00:00:15"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

logically

- neither the start nor end time of your record under test must be between start and end time of any database record - this would cover any partial overlap as well as inside overlap
- an Outside overlap is detected if test_start < db_start AND test_end > db_end

In SQL I would formulate

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Tab as T WHERE
   :param_start BETWEEN T.start_time AND T.end_time OR
   :param_end   BETWEEN T.start_time AND T.end_time OR
   (:param_start <= T.start_time AND
    :param_end >= T.end_time
   )
```

if the count is <> 0 you have an overlap

Comment: thanks, I think this is what I am looking for. didn't know about BETWEEN.

Comment: @cezar between is not an overlap, if you have 0-5 and 5-10, this reports it as "overlap" when in fact they are next to each other

Comment: in fact you don't even need the [... a BETWEEN x AND y ...], you can always translate it into [ ... a >= x AND a <= y ...], but it's an elegant formulation

Comment: A-B and B-C is not an overlap is it? They touch, but do not `over`-lap

Comment: @Richard you are correct (+1) I made an assumption which may (or may not) be incorrect in Cezar's environment. It works perfectly in my environment though. So to overcome the issue the BETWEEN .. AND needs to be reformulated and care be taken where to put  <,> and where <=,>=

Answer (score 0):

Any record that goes into the database will by nature be unique.  If you're trying to validate unique attributes, for example 'login',  you must add a 'validates :login, :uniqueness => true' line to the model,  but also in the migration file, you will want to add the following line 't.string :login, :unique => true' ... This prevents any overlap

cheers

Paul

Answer (score 0):

```
select start_time, end_time
from tbl
where start_time < "00:00:20"
  and "00:00:10" < end_time
limit 1;
```

Notes:

1. `Limit 1` is used to quickly return a result, without having to find/count all overlaps
2. The double start

   when an overlap is found, a sample overlapping record is output

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a gem that could help you solve this problem.

https://github.com/robinbortlik/validates_overlap

At readme is a examle how to use it. But at this time is only for Rails 3.

cheers

Robin Bortlík